# PHP MySQL форматирование даты

Tags: php, mysql

В базе хранится дата в формате timestamp. Мне нужно из этой даты взять только часы:минуты:секунды и потом представить эти данные в секундах для json объекта.
Остановился на том, что сейчас есть стринговые часы:минуты:секунды (на скриншоте), как их перевести в секунды ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","root");
if (!$con) die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("triger", $con);
$data = mysql_query("SELECT time(`time`) AS ts, value FROM triger1") or die ("Query error");
header("Content-type: text/json");
$V0 = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($data))
{
$V0[]= array( $row['ts'], (int) $row['value']);
}
mysql_close($con);
echo json_encode( array($V0), JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте mysql-функцию TIME_TO_SEC()

```
SELECT TIME_TO_SEC(TIME('2016-06-21 01:02:06')); // Вернет '3726'
```

Comment: Проклятье, я помню, что пробовал это, но не получалось, а сейчас работает, спасибо большое !

Comment: @D.Sakulin отметьте ответ как верный

Answer (score -1):

Вот так:

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","root");
if (!$con) die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("triger", $con);
$data = mysql_query("SELECT time(`time`) AS ts, value FROM triger1") or die ("Query error");
header("Content-type: text/json");
$V0 = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($data))
{
$V0[]= array(strtotime($ts), (int) $row['value']);
}
mysql_close($con);
echo json_encode( array($V0), JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
?>
```

P.S. парсим строку с временем по символу : и берем самый последний элемент -- секунды

Comment: Спасибо, буду знать, что и через explode можно.

Comment: не забудьте отметить ответ правильным, который подошёл Вам больше всего, чтобы не путать других :)

Comment: Судя по вопросу всё же нужно количество секунд, а не остаток этих секунд.

Comment: Вам нужно кол-во секунд строки типа `10:21:56` -- 37316?

Comment: @D.Sakulin Обратите внимание на сообщение выше